# problem with bootstrap dropdown menu classes

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

im trying to make bootstrap drop down menu but in it doesn't render as expected (the button to expand the menu is unclickable )

```html
      <div class="news-blocks mb-5">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 services-section">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="inner-align">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <h2 class="heading">
                                            <i class="la la-gears"></i> الخدمات الإلكترونية </h2>
                                        <div class="dropdown open">
                                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="triggerId" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                aria-expanded="false">
                                                تسجيل الشركة
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="triggerId">
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <p class="text">
    text
                                        </p>
                                        <button type="button" class="arrow-btn btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

the area highlited in red should be the dropdown menu but it is not

Comment: Are you on angular ?

Comment: no , its just html in oracle webcenter portal